# How to get url parameter in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have been trying to get the url parameter in Angular, but this is not a Single Page application. I tried the below code snippet.

```
www.example.com?param1=ABC
```

Injected `$location` in controller, then

```
var paramValue= $location.search().param1;
```

In the above case, paramValue is undefined. But, If I change the url to

`www.example.com#?param1=ABC`  (Added # in the URL) it works.

But, I don't want to do this because it breaks the page since it is not SPA.

Can someone suggest a better way to get the url parameter without using # in the url?

Answer (score 0):

try this..

inject `$stateParams` into the contoller

```
var paramValue=$stateParams.param1
```

this will work in your scenario

Answer (score 0):

Use this if you are not using stateParams:

```
this.$routerOnActivate = function(next) {
    $scope.paramValue= next.params.param1;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

> First enable the html5 mode:

Add the following code in router:

```
app.config(["$locationProvider", function($locationProvider) {   
           $locationProvider.html5Mode(true); 
}]);
```

> Second, Then update the index.html

```
<head>
    ...
    <base href="/">
</head>
```

> Finally, Inject the $stateParams into the contoller and access using
>   following

```
var paramValue=$stateParams.param1
```

Answer (score 0):

use `$routeParams`

In AngularJs in your $routeProvider

```
.when('/sample/:id',
  {
     templateUrl: 'sample.html',
     controller: 'sampleController'
  })
```

In your controller get it with `$routeParams.id`

Comment: This is not SPA application, I have clearly mentioned